# Building Qt 4.8.x

Tags: c++, qt4, qtwebkit

I am trying to build Qt 4.8.x version in a 64 bit machine (msvc-2008). I always end up with the following error:

```
CurrentTime.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__timeEndPeriod @4 referenced in function "double __cdecl WTF::currentTime(void)" (?currentTime@WTF@@YANXZ)
CurrentTime.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__timeBeginPeriod@4 referenced in function "double __cdecl WTF::currentTime(void)" (?currentTime@WTF@@YANXZ)
..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\QtWebKitd4.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Could anyone please shed some light? Am I missing any obvious windows dependencies? If yes, to which .vcproj file should I add it?

I already tried adding winmm.lib in QtWebKit.vcproj but it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem now.